# python server how to update Google Play Developer API version to 3

Tags: google-api-python-client

I use python for google in-store backend verification,but Received a warning：
**We've detected that your app is using an old version of Google Play Developer API. From December 1 2019,version1 and 2 of this API will no longer be available. Update to version 3 before this date. Note that this is not related to the AIDL/Billing Library deprecation.**

Here is the "**v3**",Is it version 3
googleapiclient.discovery.build("androidpublisher","v3",credentials=credentials,cache_discovery=False)

Please tell me how to upgrade?thank you.

```
version:
google-api-python-client==1.7.11
google-auth==1.6.3
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.
```

this is my code:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import googleapiclient.discovery

packagename = "xxx.xxxxxx.xxxxx"
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = xxxxx.json
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
service=googleapiclient.discovery.build("androidpublisher","v3",credentials=credentials,cache_discovery=False)
logging.getLogger('googleapiclient.discovery').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
res=service.purchases().subscriptions().get(packageName=packagename,subscriptionId=self.sku,token=self.token).execute()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fJEr.jpg)